# How to style plotly dash border so they don't overlap anymore?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly

I'm currently developing a web app where users can upload data for analysis, and I'm encountering an issue with overlapping borders in my app's UI. As shown in the image I've provided, there are two borders that should be separate but are overlapping each other.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and prevent the overlapping borders in my web app's interface.

[image: Projects UI]

`main.py

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table, Input, Output, State


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)



# Layout

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs([
        dcc.Tab(label="Analyzer", children=[
            html.Div([
                dcc.Upload(
                    id='upload-data',
                    children=html.Div([
                        'Drag and Drop or ',
                        html.A('Select Files')
                    ]),
                    style={
                        'width': '100%',
                        'height': '60px',
                        'lineHeight': '60px',
                        'border': '2px dashed #aaaaaa',
                        'border-radius': '20px',
                        'text-align': 'center',
                        'padding': '10px',
                        'margin': '0 auto',
                        'display': 'block'
                    },
                    multiple=True
                ),
            ], className='upload-section'),

            html.Div([
                html.Button(
                    'Analyze',
                    id='process-button',
                    n_clicks=0,
                    className='action-button',
                    style={
                        'background-color': '#0074D9',
                        'color': 'white',
                    }
                ),
                html.Button(
                    'Remove Uploaded Files',
                    id='remove-files-button',
                    n_clicks=0,
                    className='action-button',
                    style={
                        'background-color': '#FF4136',
                        'color': 'white',
                    }
                ),
            ], className='action-buttons', style={'text-align': 'center', 'margin': '0 auto', 'padding': '10px'}),


            html.Div(id='output-data-upload')
        ]),
    ],
    style={'margin': 'auto', 'width': '80%'}
    )
], style={'border': '2px solid #aaaaaa', 'border-radius': '20px', 'margin': '10%', 'padding': '20px'})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I've already tried several solutions to fix this problem, including using external stylesheets in the 'assets' folder, but none of them have resolved the issue. I initially attempted to address the problem with CSS within the Python file as it seemed like a straightforward and comprehensive approach, but it didn't work.

Comment: By removing the css declaration `'width': '100%'` from the upload component, it looks fine.